# Achieving pop-up over index with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an ideia for my website which consists of making something like this:
[image]
Basically I want have this little pop-up over the image, which would contain some text content.

I already have everything else HTML/CSS wise working. I currently have (using bootstrap) a row and 2 columns, the column with the image is just a div with a background-image and the other col is just some text on a flex-box. How can I achieve what I want using bootstrap or some other CSS features?

Comment: have you tried using overflow-y? overflow-x?

Comment: Please include code SO is not a place for asking for code it is for fixing it

Comment: Make the container `position: relative`, and the pop-up `position: absolute`, and then position it with the `left` and `top` CSS rules. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I have no code to post because I have literally no idea on how to start doing it as I'm a beginner on both HTML and CSS, and now I'm sure you also don't have any code to show.

Comment: Will try @Mr.Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just example, maybe helpful for you.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg" width="100%">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Foobar</h3>
    <h5>More Beer, more party</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```